# how to call a method in iphone applications?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-3.2

i have a method in delegate.m file

```
-(void) switchToTabbarController  
{ 
  TabBarController *tabBarController = 
  [[TabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabBarController" bundle:nil];
  [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

and i wanted to call this method from my LoginView Method. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you do not want to call it this way. I prefer not to call the UIApplication from  a view and try to prevent it from a controller. Use a notification instead.

But the way you could do this is:

```
[(ApplicationDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate switchToTabbarController]
```

Comment: thanks for da ans Mats:) but i have a question what does [(ApplicationDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate switchToTabbarController] mean?? ............. Do i need to add this line of code in my login.M file

Comment: Did i misunderstand. I assumed the following: Delegate is your application delegate. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

At first you have to import the header, and then create the object of your Delegate class, and then call the method. It will look like this:

```
#import "Delegate.h"
```

In place where you want to call it:

```
Delegate* del=[[Delegate alloc] init];
[del switchToTabbarController];
```

And after you are done, I would strongly suggest reading Apple's Objective-C Programming Guide:
[Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/introduction/introobjectivec.html).

EDIT: if this is your AppDelegate, go with Mats' solution.

Answer (score 1):

include header file -
  #include

create instance of this class 
   delegate *d=[[delegate alloc] init];
    [d  switchToTabbarController];